# Как сгенерировать документацию с помощью doxywizard в отдельном файле?

Tags: c++, документация, doxygen

при генерации документации c помощью doxywizard в папку с библиотекой добавляются 2 папки прямо в проект:

```
latex/ и html/
```

Можно ли настроить doxywizard так чтобы он генерировал все нужные ему папки и файлы в отдельном месте, например в папку "documentation/"?

На скрине мои настройки, больше ничего не менял
[image: Настройки моего doxywizard]

Comment: Было бы проще, если бы вы разместили свой вопрос на англоязычном форуме на stackexchange (я перевел все с помощью Google Translate), думаю, вам стоит взглянуть на OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, expert -> project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел параметр отвечающий за генерацию документации в определенном месте:
[image: Параметр]